# Can I call a .NET 4.7.1 DLL from a 4.6.1 web app?

Tags: asp.net, .net, version

I am developing an ASP.NET application and, for various reasons, I am using .NET 4.6.1 for this, with no option to upgrade to 4.7.1. From this web app I would like to call a DLL that has been compiled for 4.7.1. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No.Calling up higher versions in low versions is not possible

Comment: Thank you. Can you point to any source or documentation that backs this up?